# Exposing an entity using JMSSerializerBundle and FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, jmsserializerbundle

[Using Symfony2, JMSSerializerBundle, FOSUserBundle, Doctrine ORM]

The `User` entity is associated with the `PersonalDetails` entity. 
Using JMSSerializer I cannot get `PersonalDetails` exposed when serializing `User`.

`User` entity

```
/* AppBundle\Entity\User.php

    /** @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="PersonalDetails", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist","remove"}) */
    protected $personalDetails;
```

Serializer conifg

```
# app/serializer/FOSUserBundle/Model.User.yml

FOS\UserBundle\Model\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        username:
            expose: true
        email:
            expose: true
        roles:
            expose: true
        personalDetails:
            expose: true
```

`Username`, `Email`, and `Roles` all expose just fine. `PersonalDetails` has it's own `@Expose` annotations that all work fine when serializing just the `PersonalDetails` result. What am I missing?

How can I properly expose the `PersonalDetails` entity with this configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oph! Feeling like an idiot. I was telling `FOSUserBundle`'s `User` entity to expose `PersonalDetails`, but I should be telling `AppBundle\Entity\User` to expose.

The fixed code:

```
    use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose 

    /** 
      *@Expose()
      *@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="PersonalDetails", mappedBy="user", cascade=   {"persist","remove"}) */
    protected $personalDetails;
```